# Why do I need to explicitly load my relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, laravel-8

I have two basic models.
`PriceRule` && `ProductOffer`.

A price rule has many offers.

```
public function productOffers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductOffer', 'price_rule_id');
}
```

When I test that model, I (sometimes) need to explicitly load that relation with `...->load( 'productOffers')` for the collection to be filled properly. For example :

```
$priceRule = PriceRule::factory()->create([
       'title' => 'Product Categories',
       'description' => 'Find this price rule with product categories',
       'value' => 10,
       'value_type' => 'flat_price',
]);

$priceRule->title = 'Updated Product Categories';
$priceRule->save();
dd($priceRule->productOffers);
```

In this example, `productOffers` will be an empty collection.

```
$priceRule = PriceRule::factory()->create([
       'title' => 'Product Categories',
       'description' => 'Find this price rule with product categories',
       'value' => 10,
       'value_type' => 'flat_price',
]);

$priceRule->title = 'Updated Product Categories';
$priceRule->save();
$priceRule->load('productOffers');
dd($priceRule->productOffers);
```

In this example, `productOffers` will be a properly filled collection.

I think the issue might be in the fact that the `productOffers` are created in a save observer when I save the `PriceRule`. It still doesn't explain why I need to explicitly load it. Shouldn't the relation call `$priceRule->productOffers` load it on the fly?

Could my problem also be because `$priceRule` is a simple reference to what was created by the factory and not the Eloquent Object itself? If so, is it possible to create it differently so that I don't need to load all relations by hand.

Comment: Can you show how you set the relationship through the observer?

Comment: Instead `$priceRule->productOffers` call `$priceRule->productOffers()`, which will load the relationship. No relationship is loading on the fly automaticly, if you dont specify it in model.

Comment: @Autista_z calling the relationship method directly does not 'load' a relationship, it returns a relationship object that you can then do a query on

Comment: @Autista_z Exactly. It doesn't return the collection but a simple `get()` will do it. I find that way better than loading the relationship. Thanks a lot.